# inputting data from an array into a database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get information into my database and am running into a problem that I am sure I am just making a simple mistake.  To update the table I am using:

```
    $conn->query("update webPrice set price= " . $amazonResult['price'] . " where asin = '" . $amazonResult['asin'] . "'");
```

$conn is my connection.  The price is consistently entered as 0.  I know there is information there since when I do print_r($amazonResult) I see everything that I want to insert into the DB.  Code to get amazon info is:

```
    foreach($parsed_xml->GetMyPriceForASINResult as $item ) {
 $asin2 =$item->attributes()->ASIN;
$current = $item->Product;

 $status = $item->attributes()->status;

      if (stristr($status, "Success") == true)
{
        $amazonResult = array(
                        'asin' => $asin2,
            'price' => $current->Offers->Offer->BuyingPrice->ListingPrice,//AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->
                            );
```

I think the issue is with my update statement, but I an not sure what it is.  The asin info is entered correctly.  the fields are price = double and asin = varchar.

**EDIT:**  here is the result of print_r($amazonResult);

```
Array ( [asin] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0176055452 ) [price] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [CurrencyCode] => USD [Amount] => 10.11 ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, adding quotes `'` around `$amazonResult['price']`

```
$conn->query("update webPrice set price= '" . $amazonResult['price'] . "' where asin = '" . $amazonResult['asin'] . "'");
```

**Edit:** As per your edit, as the values are in objects,

```
$conn->query("update webPrice set price= '" . $amazonResult['price']->Amount . "' where asin = '" . $amazonResult['asin']->0 . "'");
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried your suggestion, and get the same result.

Comment: Edited my answer, as per the edit in the question. Take a look.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple.  Thanks, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the names of the table and the fields in between two of this sign: ` And You have to use the ' sign for values. (like coder1984 said)

```
$conn->query("update `webPrice` set `price` = '" . $amazonResult['price'] . "' where `asin` = '" . $amazonResult['asin'] . "'");
```